# Image slide show viewer for Windows with discreet image switching

Tags: windows, gratis, images, image-viewer, slideshow

I have a laptop (running Windows 7) that is connected to two external monitors most of the time. When it is connected to the external monitors I do not use the screen on the laptop at all, however it is not possible to turn of the laptop monitor so it's always on.

I want an image slideshow program to use as a "screensaver" that I can run in fullscreen on the screen to avoid burn-in. Bonus if it can grab my photos from google, flicker or generate nice patterns on its own without me having to have a bunch of photos available locally on the computer.

**Requirements (must have):**

- Free (gratis) Windows 7 standalone program (i.e. not a chrome plugin)
- Runs in fullscreen
- I can select which monitor it should run on.
- Changes images discretely (for example using moderately slow cross-fade or similar). Just switching from one image directly to another catches my attention and distracts me since the screen is always in the corner of my eye.

**Nice to haves in order of preference (has preferably one of these features):**

- Google photos integration so it can display photos from my photo library.
- Shows nice automatically generated geometrical patterns or similar (similar to audio visualizers without requiring audio input to display something nice to watch)
- Flicker integration so it can display random photos from Flickr.
- Slideshow using all photos in a local directory on the computer.